# Magento enabling compilation error : need permanent solution

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, compiler

i was tried to enable compilation and got error. And admin & frontend was not accessable.

its happens with me many time on different site. and then i disable compiler from code.

i made comment below given code in path 'includes/config.php'

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

But its look ilke temporary solution. want to know why its happen. i mean what if i want to enable compiler. ?

error was

```
magento Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required public_html/medomain/includes/src/../lib/vendor/autoload.php
```

Even i am not enabling it directly just tried to compile it getting this error.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjij44tmrcfff01/Screenshot%202016-10-03%2017.24.52.png?dl=0

Comment: Have you run compilation before enable it ?

Comment: i am not enabling it. just run compilation. and get this error https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjij44tmrcfff01/Screenshot%202016-10-03%2017.24.52.png?dl=0

Comment: src folder existing in include folder ?

Comment: yes, src folder is available in include folder

Comment: What does the following class look like `Fontis_Australia_Model_Observer`?

Comment: Rename or delete src folder under include, after run compiler and check agian